# Exibir aviso para navegador específico

Tags: android, jquery-ui

Tenho uma aplicação web que funciona bem em todos os navegadores.

Ocorre que precisei desenvolver uma feature que não está respondendo bem no navegador que já vem instalado nos smartphones da Samsung. Pelos meus relatórios do Analytics, uma boa parcela dos meus usuários utilizam este navegador.

Eu gostaria de exibir um aviso logo no carregamento da página para todos os usuários que fazem uso deste navegador, informando que é melhor que eles utilizem o Chrome ou o Opera, por exemplo.

Isto tem que ser feito logo no carregamento da página, antes que cheguem a acessar esta feature que desenvolvi recentemente.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já, agradeço!!!

Comment: Já tentou isso https://www.sitepoint.com/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/ parceiro ?

Comment: Conheço esse script, talvez tenha que adaptar para um navegador específico.. https://jsfiddle.net/9atsffau/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode detectar o utilizador com o comando : `navigator.userAgent.match(REGEX DO NAVEGADOR A CHECAR);`

Por exemplo,

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

Então no seu onLoad você pode chamar : `if( isMobile.Android() ) alert('Android');`

Desta forma, creio que você tenha que ver qual o "useragent" que o navegador da Samsung envia e tratar ele.

Existe também algumas bibliotecas que ajudam nisso, mas nunca cheguei a utilizar, por exemplo  [MobileESP project](http://blog.mobileesp.com/).

Trechos de código acima foram retirados deste [site](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript).